# ReferenceError when using 'let' to declare variable through a ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I've seen code where a ternary operator is used to check whether or not a variable has been declared, and declare it if it has not been. For example:

```
var num = (typeof num === 'undefined' ? 1 : num);
console.log(num); //1
```

However, this does not work when using 'let' instead of 'var':

```
let num = (typeof num === 'undefined' ? 1 : num); //Uncaught ReferenceError: num is not defined
```

I know that compared to 'var', 'let' has block scoping and prevents redeclaration. I'm unsure how this would cause the ReferenceError in the case above. Could anyone shed some light as to what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: [*Temporal Dead Zone*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/218196). You are trying to read the variable before it was initialized.

Comment: You can't access `let` before defining it. while `var` you can it will be `undefined`

Comment: This is because TDZ. You ca refer this answer for details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779662/10150695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into something called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Hoisting affects `var` declaration, but not `let` or `const`.

In short words, hoisting moves every `var` declaration to the top of the code. Meaning for this code:

```
x = 1;
var y = x + x;
var x;
```

It is translated to:

```
var y;      // y is declared, but undefined (thus y === undefined)
var x;      // x is declared, but undefined (thus x === undefined)
x = 1;      // x is defined
y = x + x   // y is defined
```

Which is why you don't get an error, because `x` is declared, then defined.

But that is not the case for `let` and `const`:

```
x = 1;
let y = x + x;
let x;
```

will throw an error, because you used `x` before it is declared.

**EDIT**

Read Felix's comment below for details.

Comment: Almost. The same algorithm that finds all `var` declarations before the code is executed also finds all `let` and `const` declarations. The difference is that `var` declarations are *initialized* with `undefined`, whereas `let` and `const` are not initialized. Trying to access an uninitialized bindings causes an error. I'd actually avoid the terms "declared" and "defined" because they are not clearly defined (no pun intended). A *binding* (the general term for the result of `var`/`let`/`const` declarations) either exists or does not exist and it is either initialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to check variable existence. You should not do it by accessing variable.

If you have to do it do it using:

```
var barIsDeclared = true; 
try{ bar; }
catch(e) {
    if(e.name == "ReferenceError") {
        barIsDeclared = false;
    }
}
```

You get `reference error` in case of `const`and `let` variables. It may appear that they are not hoisted in the first iteration phase but that is **not true**.

Anyway, this is how I test variable existence and it works with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to access to it before initializing it.

```
let num;
num = (typeof num === 'undefined' ? 1 : num);
console.log(num); //1
```

this is the actual answer you want.